# Using (click)="" on dynamic hyperlinks

Tags: angular

I have an empty array and this is how I push an item into it, which includes an `<a>` tag:

```js
this.errors.push('At least 1 <a (click)="jumpToError($event)" href="">service</a> should be added.');
```

```html
<ul *ngFor="let error of errors">
  <li [innerHTML]="error"></li>
</ul>
```

When the user clicks on that link, I want to invoke the following function:

```js
jumpToError(event: MouseEvent): void {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log('Clicking works!')
}
```

My problem is, when I click on that link, the same page will be reloaded and I can't see whether the function has been invoked or not.

Comment: Yeah this won’t work. Angular will not process that at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment angular will not process the link cause the event
will not register,

The best way to do this is to put all the errors in the page, you can
create a map which will include visibility of each error:

```
<div *ngIf="errorsMap.get('myError').isError">
      <a (click)="jumpToError($event)" href="">service</a>
</div>
```

But to be honest, I'm not sure what is your use case, why you need this.